# How to download wav or mp3 file from url PHP? Url playing my clip after authentication

Tags: php, yii, download

```
I used the following code to play my url and its working fine.
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="url.wav" type="audio/x-wav"></video>
```

> And tried the following code for download

```
header('Content-Type: audio/x-wav');
$file = "url.wav";
if( !file_exists($file) ) die("File not found");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($file) . "");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
header('Content-Type: audio/x-wav, audio/wav');
readfile($file);
```

> I am using all code in view file of Yii framework.

Comment: And where is the question ?

Comment: Downloading not initiated. I want to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

In `Yii`, you can do this like below in your controller:

```
return Yii::app()->request->sendFile($file, @file_get_contents($file),'audio/x-wav');
```